# Handle click listeners in a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on custom adapter. I created separate class for it which extends BaseAdapter. I am having two images - (minus) and + (plus) which will decrease or increase quantity of product in list view.

List item looks like

[ -  Product  qty  + ]

Now I already implemented listener for - (minus) image and it is working. But listener for + (plus) image is not working. I printed qty on the console it is incrementing but not getting updated in listview.

Here is the code

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_sold_item, null);

    TextView txtListItem = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem);
    txtQuantity = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
    ImageView imgCancel = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgCancel);
    ImageView imgPlus = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus);

    HashMap<String, String> mapData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapData = data.get(position);

    txtListItem.setText(mapData.get("product"));
    txtQuantity.setText(mapData.get("qty"));

    imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doButtonOneClickActions(position);
        }
    });

    imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qtyClickAction(position);
        }
    });

    return vi;
}

private void qtyClickAction(int rowNumber) {
    System.out.println(rowNumber);
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
    System.out.println("before : " + qty);
    qty++;
    txtQuantity.setText("" + qty);
    System.out.println("after : " + qty);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void doButtonOneClickActions(int rowNumber) {
    // Do the actions for Button one in row rowNumber (starts at zero)
    System.out.println("rowNumber : " + rowNumber);
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
    if (qty == 1) {
        data.remove(rowNumber);

    } else {
        txtQuantity.setText("" + --qty);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

One more thing, if I delete item in list, it is getting deleted. But how can I get notification for deleted item in my main class. Consider I selected 3 items, now I removed any one item by clicking - (minus). The item is getting deleted from list - the code is in adapter class

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But how can I update total amount which is getting calculated in main class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it may help you,

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_sold_item, null);

    TextView txtListItem = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem);
    TextView txtQuantity = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
    ImageView imgCancel = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgCancel);
    ImageView imgPlus = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus);

    HashMap<String, String> mapData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapData = data.get(position);

    txtListItem.setText(mapData.get("product"));
    txtQuantity.setText(mapData.get("qty"));

    imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doButtonOneClickActions(txtQuantity,position);
        }
    });

    imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qtyClickAction(txtQuantity,position);
        }
    });

    return vi;
}

private void qtyClickAction(TextView txtQuantity,int rowNumber) {
    System.out.println(rowNumber);
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
    System.out.println("before : " + qty);
    qty++;
    txtQuantity.setText("" + qty);
    System.out.println("after : " + qty);
}

private void doButtonOneClickActions(TextView txtQuantity,int rowNumber) {
    // Do the actions for Button one in row rowNumber (starts at zero)
    System.out.println("rowNumber : " + rowNumber);
    int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
    if (qty == 1) {
        data.remove(rowNumber);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        txtQuantity.setText("" + --qty);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It is working... But I did not get the logic. I already declared public TextView txtQuantity; at the starting point of class

Comment: Sorry friend I am not having enough reputation to vote up. :( Can you give me one answer for -- how can I get notification for deleted item in my main class

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private void qtyClickAction(TextView txtQuantity,int rowNumber) {
System.out.println(rowNumber);
int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim());
System.out.println("before : " + qty);
qty++;
data.get(rowNumber).set("qty")=qty;
//txtQuantity.setText("" + qty); not needed anymore
System.out.println("after : " + qty);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

indeed you have not updated the data model so notifyDataSetChanged(); dose not take effect.

In order to send back updated data:

```
imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doButtonOneClickActions(position);
        // update totalAmount
         txtAmountAdapter.setText(Integer.valueOf(totalAmount).toString()));

    }
});

imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        qtyClickAction(position);
         // update totalQty
        txtAmountAdapter.setText(Integer.valueOf(totalAmount).toString()));

    }
});
```

and pass txtAmount to the constructor of your adapter and store it as txtAmountAdapter. now every update in total amount update txtAmount in main.

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException  this exception throws because you pass number in setText, convert it to string and then pass it

Comment: hey can you send me entire code on paritoshvaidya@gmail.com also can we discuss on hangouts / gtalk

Comment: I am not familiar with hangouts / gtalk. i can check your project and fix it, if you want send a runnable portion of it and i will change it to update the total qty if it runs and have not any further bugs;-) if all your problem is this (sending back the result) i will help you, else try it yourself. i will run your project on genymotion emulator and will fix it by using this emulator , if i must run it on real device i can not help you know.

Comment: Shall I add my question as a new question to stack overflow with detailed code ?

Comment: sure update your question with all necessary codes. i will see and check it, your main activity, your adapter and any further codes you think i must see

Comment: I will add it as new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187400/updating-textview-on-activity-once-data-in-adapter-class-is-changed Please check